# Mal salida a pantalla de este programa

Tags: java

Tengo este código.

```
  public static void añadir(CListaTfonos listatfnos){
        try {               
            String nombre;
            String direccion;
            long telefono;

             System.out.println("telefono: ");
            telefono=leer.nextLong();

            System.out.println("direccion: ");
            direccion=leer.nextLine();

            System.out.println("nombre: ");
            nombre=leer.nextLine();

            listatfnos.añadir(new CPersona(nombre, direccion, telefono));                
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Al mostrar en pantalla me debe mostrar algo como esto

```
teléfono: 12345
dirección: ejemplo
nombre: jose
```

el problema es que en la pantalla al correr el programa y seleccionar la opción -añadir- desde un switch me lo muestra así

```
 teléfono: 12345

 dirección: nombre: jose
```

no me deja agregar la dirección, se la salta, la brinca, la omite. **¿por qué pasa eso?** **¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?**
Si lo muevo, que quede así

```
    System.out.println("telefono: ");
    telefono=leer.nextLong();
    System.out.println("nombre: ");
    nombre=leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("direccion: ");
    direccion=leer.nextLine();
```

lo muestra así

```
 teléfono:12345

 nombre: dirección: ejemplo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El Inconveniente es que el método [nextLong()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong()) de la clase [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) lee un número [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html?is-external=true) más no detecta el `ENTER` que el usuario presiona luego de Ingresar el teléfono, dicho `ENTER` será leído por la siguiente instrucción [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) y asignado a la variable `direccion` *(o la que se encuentre después asignada por nextLine())*

Para solucionar esto bastaría con añadir un [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) antes de leer la dirección.*(después de leer el número)*

```
  System.out.println("telefono: ");
  telefono=leer.nextLong();
  leer.nextLine();
  System.out.println("direccion: ");
  direccion=leer.nextLine();
```

> Este inconveniente también se puede presentar al intentar leer un **Entero** [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()),  **Double**  [nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) , **Float** [nextFloat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat()) ,  **Short**  [nextShort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextShort()) , dado que se espera un número más no una cadena qué es lo que representa un `Enter`